# Kubernetes (on GKE) external connection through NAT for specific kube services?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I currently have two clusters on GKE - one in `eu-west1-b` and another in `us-east1-b`. The pods deployed to the nodes in these clusters need to make location-based requests (for latency testing purposes).

I also need to connect to my postgres instance on RDS, which uses IP-based whitelisting for external connections. The nodes in my clusters have ephemeral IPs so I can't use them.

I have done a lot of research and gone through lots of SO answers and docs and tutorials and come to the solution that routing traffic through a NAT is pretty much the best/only way to do this right now on GKE.

https://serverfault.com/questions/835425/kubernetes-external-connection-through-single-ip

Similar to that question above, I don't want to route all of my traffic through the NAT. My reason is because I need my requests to come from the internet gateway associated with the current node so it is coming from a particular region.

The above question has some answers that almost get me there, but doesn't include any kube-specific configuaration. This is a great tutorial:

https://docs.tenable.com/pvs/deployment/Content/GoogleCloudInstructionsNatGateway.htm

But again, is not based on kube.

My thinking is that I need to define a service for postgres in my kube cluster, and then tell that to route to the external service through the NAT. Not entirely sure where to start and would appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution:

1. [Tag](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) your instances in different zones/regions with different tags
2. Create static IP addresses for each zone/region
3. Create NAT exit nodes (GCE instances or instance groups) using the external address from above
4. Create a [route](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/routes/add) trough each of the NAT exit nodes. Restrict each route with destination IP range for your RDS ingress IP/32 and network tags from Step 1 (so the instances use the correct gateway)

Comment: I think I understand, thanks.. but.. "Create NAT exit nodes (GCE instances or instance groups) using the external address from above". So I will need compute instances for each region? I'm trying to reduce costs, if anything. I don't mind one extra instance for routing service-specific egress, but I can't afford an extra instance per region. Perhaps I'm missing something, though.

Comment: I'm afraid you aren't missing anything. In your question you said "My reason is because I need my requests to come from the internet gateway associated with the current node so it is coming from a particular region." To get different addresses for different regions you need multiple exit nodes. Even if that wasn't the case, you'd still need one per region otherwise you end up paying for inter region traffic for your egress. I suppose you could make an instance per region to do double duty (node in GKE and NAT exit) if you really need to save on that. That is doable, but not ideal.

Comment: "To get different addresses for different regions you need multiple exit nodes. Even if that wasn't the case, you'd still need one per region otherwise you end up paying for inter region traffic for your egress" << just to clarify - I don't need different addresses for diff regions. I just need the nodes to be in specific regions, and don't mind if their addresses change so long as they remain in the same region. I'm completely lost on the inter region traffic part. Hopefully I'm not building myself a huge transfer bill. I have some credits so I'll run a prod workload and find out. Thanks.

Comment: Have a read of [network pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#network).

Comment: Cheers. I've read it over a few times but it's too confusing to estimate actual cost. I'll just run a workload and see what costs come out of it. Worst case, I'll move over to a set of VPSs without such bandwidth costs. Appreciate the help.